# R: Can´t find mistake on Linear Regression

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have to reproduce the code used by http://scholar.harvard.edu/files/mankiw/files/permanent_income.pdf. I do understand the concept of linear regressions and instrumental variables, I just can´t find my mistake when writing my script.

The code first analyses a set of data and recognises endogeneity in the data and therefore implements the Instrumental Variable Approach.

Right now I´m trying to reproduce table 2[p. 272] but can´t get past the simple OLS. Yet, I´m stuck reproducing an OLS.

I´ll explain my procedure step by step and hope you guys can find my mistake.

1.- First given Table 1, in page 268 (Section 3.1), the author states he will use a specific sample. Therefore I restrict my dataset to that sample. I just left an extra row at the beginning for further steps.

```
#Load data and modification
EF <- read.delim("Z:/EF.txt", dec=",") 
View(EF) 
EF<-EF[-c(1:23), ]
View(EF)
```

2.- In the last complete paragraph of page 267, he states that for table 2 he will divide Y and C by the lagged value of Y.

```
#Dividing by one lag of Y
Table2Y<-mat.or.vec(dim(EF)[1]-1,1)
Table2C<-mat.or.vec(dim(EF)[1]-1,1)

for (i in 2:dim(EF)[1] ) {
Table2Y[i-1] = EF$Income[i]/EF$Income[i-1]
Table2C[i-1] = EF$Consumption[i]/EF$Income[i-1]
}
```

3.- In page 266 in the second paragraph of section 2, he defines the Delta Variable as the first difference.

```
#Making First Differences
Table2Y<- diff(Table2Y,1) #This is called dY in the text
Table2C<- diff(Table2C,1) #This is called dC in the text
```

3.- Then, in the notes of Table 2 in page 272 it is clearly stated the regression is dC= a+b*dY

```
lm(Table2C~Table2Y)
summary(lm(Table2C~Table2Y))
```

My result for b is .493 with a standard deviation of 0.0325. The correct results should be .296 and .044 respectively.

Can anyone provide any insight on my problem?

Comment: You missed the entire point here. You are comparing the OLS estimate with the IV estimate. Please read footnotes (The statlsttcs tn column 5 are the instrumental variables estlmate of...). See here: http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/AER/html/ivreg.html

Comment: @user227710 thanks for taking your time to answer. Would you care to explain a little bit more what the issue might be?

The results do not differ from the lm model if i use

    summary(ivreg(Table2C~Table2Y| Table2Y))

or

    summary(ivreg(Table2C~Table2Y))

Comment: You need to read manual to correctly enter the formula. I can't see the instrument (`z`) in your formula? Please google `iv in `r `` and you will find tons of helpful resources.